# I can't Unwrap a value from a plist key value

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to load a property from a nsDictionary to vTitle

```
var nsDictionary: NSDictionary?
         if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppData", ofType: "plist") {
            nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
         }
let vTitle:String = nsDictionary["LbVacationsTitle"]
```

When I debug I see the right keys in nsDictionary but I can't unwrap the value of just one key
The type of LbVacationsTitle is a string

Comment: Could you post some debugging info? Like is `path` not nil? is `nsDictionary` nil? Could you print it? Also, in Swift 4+, it's be recommended to use a Codable & PropertyList Decoder.

Comment: @Larme the path and nsDictionary was not nil. Tx for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your style preference...

```
var nsDictionary: NSDictionary?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppData", ofType: "plist") {
    nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = nsDictionary {
    let vTitle = dict["LbVacationsTitle"] as? String
    if let vt = vTitle {
        // ...
    }
}
```

...or...

```
var nsDictionary: NSDictionary?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppData", ofType: "plist") {
    nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
guard let dict = nsDictionary else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid dictionary")
    return
}
let vTitle = dict["LbVacationsTitle"] as? String
guard let vt = vTitle else {
    print("Couldn't find a string matching LbVacationsTitle")
    return
}
// ...
```

Comment: I used the second one with guard and it worked perfectly. Tx

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the `NSDictionary` API in Swift to read a property list.

There is `PropertyListSerialization` (or even `PropertyListDecoder`)

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppData", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let dictionary = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
let vTitle = dictionary["LbVacationsTitle"] as! String
```

As the file is immutable in the application bundle any crash reveals a **design** mistake

Comment: Sometimes crash is desirable